# How to start a DOS application in DOSbox in debug mode?

Tags: disassembly, debugging, dos

DOSbox compiled with `--enable-debug=heavy` option becomes a powerful reversing tool. Anytime I feel like checking the disassembly and memory state I just hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>.

But, what if I want to see the very first instructions of the program ? How do I start the application so that it immediately enters debug mode before even starting execution ?

Comment: I can't find anything about the debug mode on the wiki page. The only place where I found any info was [this](http://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?t=3944) post on VOGONS.

Comment: DOSBox may be heavily documented and open source. But, i think "How do i accomplish (X) in (Y)", where (Y) is a reverse engineering tool, is a valid question even if (Y) is heavily documented and open source.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm: Fair enough; I've retracted my close-vote and my previous comments. Thanks for presenting a reasonable argument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you build with `--enable-debug[=heavy]` and run the program via debug.com, it automatically breaks on the first instruction. See the `DOS_Execute` function in [src/dos/dos_execute.cpp](https://github.com/Henne/dosbox-svn/blob/master/src/dos/dos_execute.cpp#L479) and `DEBUG_CheckExecuteBreakpoint` in [src/debug/debug.cpp](https://github.com/Henne/dosbox-svn/blob/master/src/debug/debug.cpp#L2080).

Comment: Whoa, thank you SO much. I didn't read your answer in time and out of despair made an ugly patch to the DOSbox source which does exactly the same.